# Extract what was printed deep in the R console

Tags: r

When I execute commands in `R`, the output is printed in the console. After some threshold (I guess, some maximum number of lines), the R console no longer shows the first commands and their output. I cannot scroll up that far because it is simply no longer there.

**How can I access this "early" output if it has disappeared from the console?**

I care mostly about error messages and messages generated by my own script. I do use a script file and save my results to a file, if anyone wonders, but this still does not help solve my problem.

(I have tried saving the `R workspace` and `R history` and then loading it again, but did not know what to do next and was not able to find what I needed...)

Comment: Maybe you should use `R CMD batch`?

Comment: Does `warning()` work?

Comment: @hrbrmstr: by using `history(max=Inf)` I can only see the commands that were executed but not the output generated by the commands nor the error messages etc. I am not sure if `history()` is supposed to show those. Unfortunately, the latter (and *not* the commands) is what I need.

Comment: Argh. Yeah. My bad (& deleted). [This](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Capturing-R-console-output-into-a-file-sink-savehistory-td2227013.html) which references [this source](http://www.r-statistics.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/R-console-to-word.r.txt) has a potential solution for capturing the output.

Comment: @phoxinor: if I understand it correctly, `warning()` generates a warning (equal to the argument supplied to the function). If I type `warning()`, it works. However, I do not see how it could be relevant for my problem. Perhaps you mean function `warnings()`? It works, but it does not display any warnings (perhaps there were none).

Comment: yes sorry i meant `warnings()`, this function will return a list of the warnings R has collected so far.

Comment: that `geterrmessage()` though messages do not have an equivalent it seems...

Comment: @Roland: I guess it could be a valid solution. Personally, I would prefer some other way because I do not feel comfortable using batch, but that is only a subjective argument.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: your suggested source looks promising. Thanks! (However, this is a "precautionary" measure and will not work after the fact. E.g. I will have to run my script again instead of somehow retrieving the output that has been "lost" from my last running the script.)

Comment: Since I have not found a way to recover the lost output from the console, I ran my calculations again. This time I used function `sink()`. `sink()` with option `type="message"` will divert any messages (like error messages) to a user-specified file. `sink()` with option `type="output"` will divert what is being printed out by my script to a user-specified file. If I specify the same file for both `type="message"` and `type="output"`, I get what I would otherwise see in the console, and that is what I needed.